# pandas interpolate with nearest for non-numeric values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with numeric and non-numeric values with a datetime index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'date': datetime(2017, 4, 24, 1), 'a':1, 'b':2, 'c': "hee"},
    {'date': datetime(2017, 4, 24, 2), 'a':2, 'b':4, 'c': 'hoo'},
    {'date': datetime(2017, 4, 24, 3), 'a':4, 'b':8, 'c': 'joo'},
    {'date': datetime(2017, 4, 24, 4), 'a':8, 'b':16, 'c': 'jee'}
]).set_index('date')
```

I would like to:

- linear interpolate the numeric values; and
- get the nearest value for non-numeric values.

What is the most elegant implementation?

**Strategy 1**

Interpolate all, then `fillna`:

```
df = df.resample('20T').interpolate('linear')
df.fillna(method='nearest')
```

But... the [`nearest`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9471) method is not implemented.

**Strategy 2**

Split the numeric and non-numeric columns

```
df2 = df.resample('20T')
df_a = df2._get_numeric_data().interpolate('linear')
df_b = df2[list(set(df.columns) - set(set(df_a.columns)))].interpolate('nearest')
```

which gives an error:

> TypeError: Cannot interpolate with all NaNs.

**update**

Interpolation with the nearest method, does apply to Boolean and numeric values, but not for strings, e.g.:

```
df.resample('20T').intepolate('nearest')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `interpolate("nearest")` works fine with numeric types, a solution is to:

1. Convert your column from **string to categorical** (which is numeric)
2. **Interpolate categorical** column with `interpolate("nearest")`
3. **Map back to string** the interpolated categorical column

   ```
   def fillna_nearest(series):
       fact = series.astype('category').factorize()

       series_cat = pd.Series(fact[0]).replace(-1, np.nan) # get string as categorical (-1 is NaN)
       series_cat_interp = series_cat.interpolate("nearest") # interpolate categorical

       cat_to_string = {i:x for i,x in enumerate(fact[1])} # dict connecting category to string
       series_str_interp = series_cat_interp.map(cat_to_string) # turn category back to string

       return series_str_interp


   In [10]: df.resample('20T').interpolate().apply(fillna_nearest)
   Out[10]: 
             a          b    c
   0  1.000000   2.000000  hee
   1  1.333333   2.666667  hee
   2  1.666667   3.333333  hoo
   3  2.000000   4.000000  hoo
   4  2.666667   5.333333  hoo
   5  3.333333   6.666667  joo
   6  4.000000   8.000000  joo
   7  5.333333  10.666667  joo
   8  6.666667  13.333333  jee
   9  8.000000  16.000000  jee
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```
In [22]: df.resample('20T').interpolate().ffill()
Out[22]:
                            a          b    c
date
2017-04-24 01:00:00  1.000000   2.000000  hee
2017-04-24 01:20:00  1.333333   2.666667  hee
2017-04-24 01:40:00  1.666667   3.333333  hee
2017-04-24 02:00:00  2.000000   4.000000  hoo
2017-04-24 02:20:00  2.666667   5.333333  hoo
2017-04-24 02:40:00  3.333333   6.666667  hoo
2017-04-24 03:00:00  4.000000   8.000000  joo
2017-04-24 03:20:00  5.333333  10.666667  joo
2017-04-24 03:40:00  6.666667  13.333333  joo
2017-04-24 04:00:00  8.000000  16.000000  jee
```

Comment: almost, column C is not interpolated with "nearest" method, 3th value should equal the 4th value

Comment: @API, i'm not i understand you correctly. Column `c` - is a string column - we can't interpolate it

Comment: therefore it should get the nearest value instead of forward fill

Comment: @API, could you please define an algorithm for "nearest" method for strings?

Comment: column should become: 'hee', 'hee', 'hoo', 'hoo', 'hoo', 'joo', 'joo', 'joo', 'jee', 'jee'. Because these are the nearest values.

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I need.

Comment: with nearest I mean the nearest datetime row with a none-Nan value